# Can Image textures be mapped to empty object like procederual textures?

Tags: texturing, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

I try to map an image texture to an Empty object (a plain axes) in blender. However, unlike procedural textures, the image texture appears streaky. Here is a picture:

[image]

The texture is supposed to be some light brown tiles. A picture of what the texture (kind of) looks like:

[image]

The image is stretched. I have another project that has the same texture in it, and it is different sizes on different objects. Here is a picture of that:

[image]

I'm using the blender Internal rendering engine.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

Build a setup where the image is mapped with Object coordinates and poin to the Empty object.

What you are probably missing is that, while a procedural texture has usually variable colors in the 3D space, an image has only 2D informations, so the texture is projected onto the XY plane of the Empty. The Z values are all the same, it's the same texture thet is being reproduced, that's why you see those streaks.

[image]

By rotating the empty you can project the texture on other sides of susanne, but along the Z axis of the empty you will never get a texture variance without adding something (noise texture, ...)

[image]